# JavaScript: почему нельзя назначить атрибут одной строкой при создании элемента

Tags: javascript

Вопрос взят [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document#comment-2611837445) (я решил спросить, так как самому интересно).

---

Следующий код работает как ожидается:

```js
var image = document.createElement('img');
  
image.setAttribute('src', '//w3.org/favicon.ico');
    
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v0hrbkza

---

А этот не работает:

```js
var image = document.createElement('img').setAttribute('src', '//w3.org/favicon.ico');

alert(image); // undefined

document.body.appendChild(image);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/758towdk

Почему второй код не работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `createElement` возвращает DOM-элемент, а `setAttribute` ничего не возвращает.

Comment: А вот этого не знал: что `setAttribute()` ничего не возвращает; однако не могу уловить тонкую логику:  раз он ничего не возвращает, то почему ничего не остаётся от `document.createElement('img')`?

Comment: В строке кода: `var image = document.createElement('img').setAttribute(...);` левой части присваивается то, что возвращает функция `setAttribute`, которая вызывается относительно того, что возвращает `createElement`.